# Can I make Sublime to display `\` as lambda?

Tags: haskell, sublimetext, sublimetext3

A friend who uses vim gets a very nice representation of Haskell source code. One thing I find very nice is that he gets `\` displayed as `λ`.

Is it possible to display `\` in Sublime Text 3 as `λ` for Haskell?

It seems as if this is possible for Sublime Text 2: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Lambda%20Substitution

Comment: I could never understand what people like about this trivial replacement. ``\`` is just as good as `λ`, or in fact better (I occasionally use `λ` as a variable name). Church himself originally didn't use lambda at all, but would write `id` as something like _x̂.x_. The _word_ "lambda" sure has stuck in a useful way to describe the entire framework, but IMO we could well get rid of the `λ` symbol entirely for lambda abstraction.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I mostly like it because it looks pretty :). More balanced than a lone `\`. In Emacs, it gets highlighted in a different color from an identifier `λ` anyhow. Besides, I care about what modern paper authors use far more than what Church used!

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: well, at least `λ` bears less of a danger than ``\`` to mangle strings where the latter is treated as an escape character... see what it did to your comment! — I sure agree we shouldn't care to much for what precise notation the original papers used to use, but I also think it's pretty backwards to take special actions to achieve a "better" notation which was itself only invented as a typographic approximation. If Emacs highlighted ``\`` specially that would look just as nice. _Without_ special highlighting, it's `λ` that looks like just some stray greek variable symbol to me.

Comment: I just looked over the source for the `Lambda Substitution` package you mentioned, and I can't find any obvious reason why it wouldn't work in ST3, so you may as well try it out and see. Use `git` to install it into your `Packages` directory, restart Sublime, and it should go to work. It can definitely be expanded to have more features, like only working on Haskell files, for example, and permanently saving the `λ` character in files, so if you know any Python have at it!

Comment: @MattDMo The plugin accesses the `begin_edit` and `end_edit` methods which are no longer accessible in ST3. Aside from wrapping those pieces of code in their own text commands, I didn't see anything that would cause it to break. Though I only spent a few minutes looking things over.